# JXTA CMS in JXSE 2.7

Tags: p2p, jxta

I doing a  pratical project on JXTA, a Distributed File system. Can we use JXTA CMS Content Management Service in JXSE-2.7 / 2.6? Where can i find the latest CMS jar file which i can use  with JXSE-2.7?

I have read the CMS in Mastering JXTA text.

```
import net.jxta.share.*;
import net.jxta.share.client.*;
Content[] content = cms.getContentManager().getContent();
fileList.removeAll();
for (int i=0; i<content.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(content[i].getContentAdvertisement().getName();
}
```

can we use these methods cms.getContentManager().getContent()  in Content Managemetn Service with JXSE 2.7/ 2.6 ??

Comment: Hi, I've made an edit to your question, which will shortly be visible - the question wasn't very clear. Can you re-edit your question to show the purpose of the code you've included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have led the release of JXTA 2.6 and 2.7. No one volunteered to test and maintain CMS. So, I cannot guarantee you that it works. We focussed on correcting fundamental issues/bugs in 2.6 and 2.7.

I would not rely on CMS as it is right now for production. You would need to test it thoroughly first.